# simple image scroll gallery using jquery - no plugin

Tags: jquery

I wish I can make an image gallery without using jQuery plugin.

Which all jQuery functions I can use and make an image scroll myself.

Can anybody suggest best practise.

scroll , scrollable. or can you suggest simple example. Which I can develop myself.

Comment: Why is this posted under the jquery tag if you don't want to use jquery?

Comment: They want to use jQuery, just not a jQuery plug-in I believe

Comment: Why not just look at the source code of a plugin to understand how it's done?

Comment: Correct Alex, i want to use jquer, but dont wnat to use some plugin , i hope plugin also made using jquery function only. so i want to make a gallery myself using those functions..Is it a wrong question? which all functions and area i can look more??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at this 24ways article: [Front-End Code Reusability with CSS and JavaScript](http://24ways.org/2009/front-end-code-reusability-with-css-and-javascript). There's enough material to get you started I would say.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why you'd want to write one yourself? If it's because you want to learn jQuery more thoroughly, or you want a really custom one that fair enough, and good luck! However, for ease and practicality it may be easier to just find one you can tailor to your specific needs:

http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/28-useful-jquery-sliders-you-need-to-download/